# how to detect missing primitive in request instead of defaulting the actual value to 0 in springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a rest controller that receives a Json request which is wrapped in a DTO. In that DTO I have this field.

```
@NotNull(message = "value is mandatory.")
private double value;
```

The problem is that when I send a request missing this value, I dont get a validation error because maybe the value defaults to 0.

How can I make sure that I notify the caller if this value is actually missing in the payload and not default to 0 automatically in spring?

Comment: is the wrapper for double not an option? `Double`?

Comment: Yes it is. I have a bunch of other fields

Comment: `@NotNull` on a primitive is useless as it has a default, so this won't work. Also the fact that a parameter is missing is something else as a `@NotNUll`property. If you really want to use this, use a `Double` instead of `double`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. this works okay

Answer (score 1):

Used @M.Deinum's suggestion and it worked okay. Involves avoiding using primitives

```
@NotNull(message = "value is mandatory.")
private Double value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion you can add one more annotation which helps you to avoid using zero like this

```
   @Min(1)
   @NotNull(message = "value is mandatory.")
   private double value;
```

Now it will take min value 1 so maybe it will work

Comment: This will not work because the user may want to use 0 or -1, I just want to let the user know that the value is required in the request. currently spring defaults it to 0 if missing with no error

Comment: If this and your search did not get a result then I suggest validating this value while inserting the record and if value does not presents then show the error message.